# Android JellyBean textview marquee issue

Tags: android, textview, marquee

iam building an app that has bar on the bottom with news feed and i decided to apply marquee on that textview ,but it has an issue with android 4.1 instead to scroll text he just leave textbiew static

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_bottom_news"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="#161616"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A `TextView` with `ellipsize="marquee"` will only actually marquee when it has focus. Hence the view will stop scrolling as soon as the user gives focus to some other view.

a `TextSwitcher` will be a more appropriate view to implement what you want.

Comment: a did set setSelected(true)

Comment: @Silvio Marijic: Try with `requestFocus()`, however the marquee will stop as soon as the user gives focus to some other view.

Comment: i dont understand why it works in evry other pre-JellyBean build

Comment: @Silvio Marijic: My guess is you don't have any other `focusable` view in your layout

Comment: and they have provided marquee sample in APIDemos (Level 16) witch doesnt work either -.-

Comment: @Silvio Marijic: Note that _marquee_ is related to _ellipsize_, it is not supposed to animate views or view's content, just display content that does not fit.

Comment: well probably ill do that task using TextSwitcher with some List of strings